# how to change the way explorer.exe and service.exe is started up to edit process affinity?

Tags: windows, parallel-processing, process, multicore

### how to change the way explorer.exe and service.exe is started up to edit process affinity?

normally explorer.exe and services.exe are started with 0x0f Affinity ( all 4 cores are used )

what i want is to make explorer and services to start differently for example

start /Affinity 3 explorer.exe

start /Affinity 4 services.exe

hence making the explorer.exe only use core 0 and 1

and making the services.exe use the core 2

leaving core 3 free for me to allocate at will

this would really help me a lot

p.s. i already know how to change it after it has already started, but the objective of this is making all child process is that start from explorer.exe and services.exe start with the same affinity since affinity is inherited to child processes

**thanks** for trying

Comment: **WHY** do you want to do this? Who told you that this was a good idea?

Comment: Q: WHY do you want to do this?=====================================
A: Because i launch alot of processes at start up and they take a lot of CPU, i want to devide them, instead of modifying one by one i would like to modify the source!=================================
Q:Who told you that this was a good idea?===========================
A: i tested this manually, and it works as i wanted it.

Comment: Why don't you just tidy up your machine and stop it launching so many processes at start up. Sounds like you just got too much stuff like Acrobat, iTunes etc. installed on your machine. Seriously, this does not sound like a good idea!

Comment: Are you aware that the system will schedule processes onto as many different processors as are available. If you restrict the number of processors available then you will likely slow things down. And once you've got everything up and running why do you want you all process that explorer subsequently creates to be affinitised to only half of your processors? Won't that be a waste of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by removing the explorer.exe from startup in windows components and then i added a start /Affinity 3 explorer.exe, this was some years ago so i don't remember how i did it exactly to post the complete answer, but you can search and you would find out how to stop explorer from starting then you can start it how ever u want

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine how this would help you achieve anything but the way to do it is to modify the affinity after the processes start. Enumerate the processes and do to them what you wish. You can easily do this with `EnumProcesses`.

I expect you would encounter security restrictions when you attempt this for services. Which services ever consume significant CPU anyway?

Modifying affinity is very rarely a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure that a child process doesn't inherit its parent's environment variables? [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683463.aspx) indicates that it does (or at least that it can). Otherwise, I agree: this is hardly ever a good idea.

Comment: explorer has special handling. You change your variables and then launch a new app and the new app has the new variables even though it was created by an old explorer which presumably has the old variables.

Comment: Ah yeah, I figured explorer probably had some kind of special handling. It does for everything else.

Comment: @cody all i'm saying is don't assume that explorer won't just give the new process full affinity.

Comment: Q: Are you sure that processes created by a reduced affinity explorer process inherit that affinity?=======================
A: i specifically asked before startup for a reason================
Q:Are you sure that processes created by a reduced affinity explorer process inherit that affinity?=======================
A: 100% sure unless the programmer who made it made it change it's own affinity.====================
Q:Modifying affinity is very rarely a good idea.=====================
A: Not when you know what you are doing!

Comment: Modifying affinity usually just results in processes being stuck on a limited number of processors whilst other processors lie idle.

Comment: @Shereef Since it seems that "you know what you are doing", I don't think I can be of much assistance. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful to you. Hopefully someone else will.